# How to apply a subquery on a where not exists query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code here below:

```
select * from outerb where not exists(select * from wms where 
outerb.barcode = wms.barcode);
```

id like to add this code here:

```
select concat('0',barcode) from outerb
```

Reason I am doing is this because I need to add an extra `0` before all barcodes  and join it together with the other table.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
select concat('0',barcode) as x from outerb join wms on outerb.x = 
wms.barcode;
```

but an error comes up with `Column 'barcode' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: `Column 'barcode' in field list is ambiguous` use alias to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

use the table alias name before barcode column

```
select concat('0',outerb.barcode) as x from
outerb join wms on concat('0',outerb.barcode) = wms.barcode
where not exists (select * from wms where concat('0',outerb.barcode) = wms.barcode)
```

Comment: unknown column 'outerb.x' in 'on clause'

Comment: intresting, why doesen't the `outerb.x` work? Just curious

Comment: also, how would I add in the `NOT EXISTS` query?

Comment: @Eduards, I've added it

Answer (score 0):

There is a column barcode in both tables, so you get that error. Try this:

```
select concat('0',outerb.barcode) as x 
from outerb join wms 
on concat('0',outerb.barcode) = wms.barcode;
```